# HTACCESS won’t show webp images on localhost xampp

Tags: .htaccess

Heres the bit of htaccess that is not working locally, in chrome devtools it shows status not found 404, and Type text/html.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Does browser explicitly support webp?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome [OR]
# OR Is request from Page Speed
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Google Page Speed Insights" [OR]
# OR does this browser explicitly support webp
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp [OR]
# AND does a webp image exists?
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f
# THEN send the webp image and set the env var webp
RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
# If REDIRECT_webp env var exists, append Accept to the Vary header
Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_webp
```

The code above I got from  askapache dot com/htaccess/serving-webp-images-for-png-jpg/

Ive checked the config in the apache folder and the rewrite is not commented,
and Ive tried swapping out a jpg for a webp and the webp displays no problem.

I’ve been hunting about for a solution and I’m all out of ideas….

I really need to do testing locally so any help on this would be great, I'm now going around in circles because .... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove `RewriteBase` and it will work locally.